# Twilio Flow Http Request Timeout

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to specify the timeout for the Http Request widget? If so, how can you adjust it. It seems incredibly short if background processing is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no way you can change the timeout. The Http Request has a timeout of 10 seconds. Check this out https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request  "The HTTP response from the URL you specify in a Make HTTP Request Widget must return a 2xx status code within 10 seconds to succeed, and the response body must not exceed 64kB."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP request widget within Studio has a hard timeout of 5 seconds.  I'm not certain, but the SDKs might give you some configuration control that Studio does not.

One possible work-around (depending upon your application) is to make this part of your flow asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I did make it async in a way because the backend process that it does kick off could be very slow in the future.  I then had to add some logic to make sure that things are synced up in the future.

Comment: They may want to specify in the studio that it does have a hard timeout and should tell you to be flexible.